# Guarantee Multiple Instances of an Object

Tags: design-patterns

I really don't know how to proper name this question. I have a certain scenario where I have an object that should be disposed of whenever used. The reasons for this are twofold:

1. I must guarantee that every member variable (*field*) is initialized before any new use.
2. I must guarantee that there aren't two methods of this object being called at the same time, since it's not thread-safe.

Both reasons could be covered in the object, having every public method lock the same *mutex* and initializing every variable on a private method, which is also called on every public method.

This solution is error prone and has a side effect of serializing the access on a multi-thread scenario, since I'll be locking the object before use. Of course, the call site could then create a new instance before calling a method (removing the side effect), but it's also error prone.

So I came up with a solution that I find both clean and very weird:

My object expose static methods, that have as parameters the variables necessary to both create a new instance of the object and execute the method. This static method create a instance of the object and then call the necessary method.

Of course, the constructor is private.

The first thing that I noticed when looking at this solution is that my object is looking a lot like a procedural method, of course, since every new method call requires a new object. But the responsibilities of the object fits nicely this scheme.

My questions (finally!, I know) are:

- Is there a pattern that would adhere to my requirements (always using a new instance of an object)?
- Is there a pattern describing my approach? Or is it a anti-pattern?
- Besides the fact that the object seems like a collection of procedural functions, is there any other reason for me not having this approach?

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Is there a particular language you're targeting, or do you intend for this to solicit more general advice?

Comment: I would create a new class, possibly holding no state, and replace all static methods by non-static method in the new class. No idea, if it helps, but it's better for testing and looks less weird.

Comment: @Cody: Right now, I'm working with C#, however, I think it'd be better if the answers were more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with your explanation it is just a class syntax wrapping of old procedural functions. this is actually not a class of Objects. I don't think there exist any OOP pattern involving non-OOP programming like this (except the Singleton?).

What's the point of the design like this with added memory/performance overhead of creating and destroying the one-time use object inside the functions?

By the way, you could split up the class in two classes. One for resource holding the other for operation on the resources. Let clients decide the most appropriate resource management scheme and pass the resource holding object to the methods of the operation class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what language you're using (it's good to use a tag for that). In C#, I'd do the following:

1. Make fields private and expose them only through properties.
2. Initialize fields at construction.
3. Since the class clearly needs to be thread-safe ("must guarantee that there aren't two methods of this object being called at the same time"), make it thread-safe. Protect mutable shared state with locks.
4. Implement the [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx), making the client responsible for disposing of instances.

Static methods inherently couple your concrete class to any client classes. Among other things, that makes client classes difficult to test in isolation.

Comment: Haven't really though about the testing aspect. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to ensure objects are not reused, but I can think of a number of ways you can try to encourage it.  All of thse could be gotten around if the user wanted to.

1. If the object has a single method that you call on it one time, then you can set a "state" inside the object when it's created, then you set the state to a "used" state after you call the method.  This has various problems, but is a possible solution.
2. You can force the user to "get a token" to use the object.  Then, when the object is used they have to pass that token, the object then compares the token to a "used token" list and only allows it to function if it's not there.  Again, the problem is that it basically only works if you have a single method you only call once.
3. Call dispose inside the object itself, essentially destorying whatever resources you create, so a second use would throw exceptions...